# FAKE Nuget packaging creates file as ReadOnly

Tags: nuget, f#-fake

I'm trying use the FAKE Nuget helper to generate a nuspec and package it. The problem is that when it generates a nuspec, it is set to ReadOnly. From there, when nuget.exe runs, it throws "Access Denied" when trying to do the packaging process.

What do I need to do to circumvent this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this isn't the best solution, but here's what I've done.

In my Powershell script that kicks off the FAKE script, I've added a step to change the nuspec attributes, removing the ReadOnly flag.

This seems to be doing what I need.

```
$rootDir = (Resolve-Path $pwd\)
$nuspecFile = (Join-Path $rootDir \nuspec\GeoSphere.nuspec)

Write-Host "Attempting to change the readonly status of $nuspecFile"
Set-ItemProperty $nuspecFile -name IsReadOnly -value $false
```